# How to speed up the rendering speed of layers with multiple virtual fields?

Tags: qgis, postgis, attribute-table, rendering, virtual-field

I am inputting data for power lines and tried using the normal field and imported it in PostGIS.

But the some of the data inputs I needed must be refreshed constantly to obtain. So instead I used virtual fields in those inputs.

So my project now is consist of data from PostGIS and Virtual Field.
But then I noticed the rendering speed of the lines became slow as well as the opening time of the attribute table after I added the Virtual Field in my project.

Is there a way to speed up the rendering speed of layers with multiple virtual fields?

Comment: You could create a pyqgis script which recalculates normal fields when you call it.